# shell script or awk script to delete files that first column/field is empty

Tags: shell-script

I have a bunch of CSV files in a directory. 
I want to re-name the files whose first column does not contain a number or is empty. the new file name should be filename.bad

I tried this awk command but it does not work.

```
awk '{ if (! ($1 ~ /[0-9]/)) print $1 }' *.csv .
```

The files look like this.
File1.csv:

```
123,ggg,fhghgh,fhgh
345,bla,bla,bla
```

File2.csv:

```
234,bla,bla,bla
,bla,bla,bla
```

This is a bad file since it's missing the number, so it should be rename & deleted.

Comment: *rename & deleted* - no reason to rename if it's should be deleted

Comment: I like to re-name, so I can keep a record of .bad files. I did not explain it well. I see what you are saying. so re-nameing it with the .bad extension will do the trick.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make sure it is asking for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

`$1` contains the contents of the first field, but I think you want to print the filename. Also, by default `awk` assumes the fields are separated by whitespace, but you have fields separated by commas.

We can tell `awk` to use a comma as the separator with `-F,` and in GNU awk, there's the variable `FILENAME` that contains the current file name.

Then add the test against the first field, say `$1 !~ /[0-9]/` to pick all lines where the first field does not contain a digit, or perhaps `$1 !~ /^[0-9]+$/` to pick the lines where the first field is empty or not entirely made of digits. (I'm not sure what is the exact test you want. If you need to allow for decimal points or leading minus signs, you'll need to adjust.)

So, still assuming GNU awk, something like this should print the filenames you want:

```
awk -F, '$1 !~ /^[0-9]+$/ { print FILENAME; nextfile}' *.csv
```

(Note that fully empty lines will also trigger that, and that it doesn't work if your filenames contain newlines.)

Then wrap it in a loop to rename or remove the files.

Comment: basically, what I want to accomplish is to eliminate file/s that are missing the first column id, since id is a unique identifier for a record. so in other words, any file that's missing the id will not get through the next step which is to load it into a databas. So that's what I wanted to re-name .bad, so I can review them later.

Comment: yes fully empty lines is ok. I just wanted to check for the first column since is required, so if the id is missing then that's a bad file.

Answer (score 1):

To remove *the files whose first column does not contain a number or is empty*:

Simple **`grep`** approach:

```
for f in *.csv; do grep -Eq '^(,|[^0-9])' "$f" && rm "$f"; done
```

Comment: how can I rename it .bad , so I can keep it in a bad file directory.

Comment: @danielcaceres, just replace `rm "$f"` with `mv "$f" "$f".bad`

Comment: this is great. thanks everyone for your help. one more ask. how can also check to ensure that every file has 12 columns?

Comment: it did not rename the file it just put .bad but omitted the file name

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for f in *csv; do   
    awk -F, '$1!~/^[0-9][0-9]*$/{exit 1}' "$f" || echo rm -- "$f"
done
```

The `awk` script will exit with a non=0 exit status if any of the lines in your input file have a 1st (comma-delimited) field that doesn't consist entirely of one or more numbers. The `||` means "do what is on the right if what is on the left fails", so it will `rm` the file if the `awk` exits with a non-0 exit status. Remove the `echo` to have it actually delete the files.

Alternatively, you could just do:

```
for f in *csv; do grep -q '^,' "$f" && echo rm -- "$f"; done
```

So if any line starts with a `,`, delete the file. But that will miss any lines whose 1st field isn't a number. If you also want those, you can use:

```
for f in *csv; do grep -qE '^(,|[^0-9]+),' "$f" && echo rm -- "$f"; done
```

Comment: great solution too. yes , basically what I want to accomplish is. if the id column is not a number then, that's a bad file and I should not proceses it, but I like to rename it .bad, so I can look at it later on. the idea is to proceses only files that have the ID in it. thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: both solutions are very well thought out. thank you. how can I re-name them with the extension .bad instead of deleting it? thanks a lot.

Comment: @danielcaceres please make sure your question always asks for what you actually want. Anyway, just replace the `rm -- "$f"` with `mv -- "$f" "$f".bad` in both solutions.

Comment: I agreed. thanks a lot. one more question. how can also check in the same script to ensure the file has 12 columns? I really appreciated all your input and responses, very well thought out.

Answer (score 0):

Below command  renames the file whose first column is empty or first column doesn’t contains digits

Command:

```
awk -F ","  '$1=="" || $1 ~ !”[0-9]” {print "mv" " "  FILENAME " " FILENAME".bad"}' * | sh
```

IF You want  to delete the files whose first column is empty or  first column doesn’t contains digits .

```
awk -F ","  '$1=="" || $1 ~ !”[0-9]” {print  “rm -rvf” “ “ FILENAME}’ * | sh
```